# NSURL "missing argument for parameter in call" Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsurl

I use obj-c and swift classes together. And at one swift class, I try to convert objective c code to swift. However, I have a problem about NSURL.

the original code is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://", appItem.URLSchema]];
```

and URLSchema is declared in the header file like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *URLSchema;
```

I convert the objective c code which is above to swift:

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string:"%@://",relativeToURL: appItem.URLSchema)
```

but it says "missing argument for parameter "path" in call"

when I try this:

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("%@://", appItem.URLSchema)
```

it says extra argument in call.

what do you suggest to convert it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument : `RelativeToURL` has the type `NSURL` and you pass a String

Try this :

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(appItem.URLSchema)://")
```

For more informations, you can take a look on the 'String Interpolation' section in the "Swift programming langage" [iBook](https://itun.es/fr/jEUH0.l).

> String interpolation is a way to construct a new String value from a
>   mix of constants, variables, literals, and expressions by including
>   their values inside a string literal. Each item that you insert into
>   the string literal is wrapped in a pair of parentheses, prefixed by a
>   backslash